# how to change the Size and color of Marquee text field in ActionScrtipt3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, marquee

I have a class for [MarqueetextField](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/408/comment-page-1#comment-14411), I am trying to change the text inside a marquee tag and the color of the marquee using as3.I Don't Know how to Change the Color and Size,kindly anybody Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RC told you to do something like this.

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "Super Long Message Goes Here ";
tf.textColor = 0xFF0000; // <----------------------------------
tf.x = tf.y = 300;
addChild(tf);
var t:Timer = new Timer(200);
t.addEventListener(
    TimerEvent.TIMER,
    function(ev:TimerEvent): void
    {
        tf.text = tf.text.substr(1) + tf.text.charAt(0);
    }
);
t.start();
```

or this:

```
var tf:MarqueeTextField = new MarqueeTextField();
tf.text = "Super Long Message Goes Here ";
tf.textColor = 0xFF0000; // <------------------------
tf.x = tf.y = 300;
tf.marquee(200);
addChild(tf);
```

Comment: am trying to Change the Size of text(tf.textSize),its not Working.Is any Method for reduce the Size?

Comment: var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.size = 35; i got it Sir

Answer (score 1):

Since it extends the Textfield class, you should be able to change the properties like [textColor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#textColor).

Comment: Sir i pass the Single Marquee text,if i use another Class For text Color i cannot Assign Same  variable for Single object

Comment: The MarqueetextField extends the Textfield class, which means you can access all the public properties that Textfield has, on an instance of MarqueetextField. Like in Neoraptor's example: tf.textColor = 0xFF0000;